# How to Call an AWS ALB from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

How can I call an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) from a back-end NodeJS/Express app?  The ALB does have an IP and DNS Name so I should be able to use one of those.

My solution is structured as follows:

```
Public Subnet
  ALB
    Welcome Page (web app)
    Members UX API
    Admin UX API
Private Subnet
  ALB
    Auth Data API
    Logging Data API
    Ticketing Data API
    Messaging Data API
```

All of the APIs are auto-scaled ECS instances spread across two availability zones.  The goal is for either of the UX APIs to be able to call any of the data APIs.

The goal is to reference the upstream endpoint in the task definition.  The Terraform snippet would be something like:

```
{
   "name"  : "UPSTREAM_DATAAPI",
   "value" : "${aws_lb.private_lb.dns_name}"
}
```

... or, if it's easier to look at, the task definition is ...

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "memberuxapi_task" {
  family                        = "memberuxapi_task"
  network_mode                  = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities      = ["FARGATE", "EC2"]
  cpu                           = 512
  memory                        = 2048
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.crms_task_execution_role.arn

  depends_on = [aws_lb.private_lb]

  container_definitions         = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "memberuxapi"
      image     = "123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/complexapi:latest"
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 2048
      essential = true
      environment = [
        {
          "name"  : "NODE_PORT", 
          "value" : "80"
        },
        {
          "name"  : "NODE_ALIAS", 
          "value" : "MEMBER_UX_API"
        },
        {
          "name"  : "UPSTREAM_DATAAPI",
          "value" : "${aws_lb.private_lb.dns_name}"
        }
      ],
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort      = 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```

Comment: And your terraform code is?

Comment: @MarkoE Which blocks would you want?  There's already a snippet where I'm setting the API's environment variable for the upstream ALB.

Comment: Ok, so you need to use the interpolation syntax then, but I don't know where the task file is, are you using any built-in functions to populate it etc.

Comment: @MarkoE : I've expanded the snippet to show the entire task definition and how I've been referencing the upstream ALB.

Comment: You could try with interpolation syntax instead of using `format` if the ALB is defined at the same level as the task is: `"http://${aws_lb.private_lb.dns_name}/loggingapi"`.

Comment: @MarkoE : This will help with the formatting, but the question is whether or not this is the correct approach.  Is the `dns_name` accessible from an ECS instance?  The Node app in the public subnet needs to be able to call the upstream API in the private subnet.

Comment: Have you tried that already? If not, try and see if that will work. Also, are there any errors in Terraform code or you just want to know if the communication will work?

Comment: @MarkoE: Yes, all of my references have been changed to remove the `format` function and rely on interpolation.  Again, I have confirmed the upstream URI is passed into the environment variables as expected.  The problem is that I cannot access that URL from a separate subnet even with the SG wide open to 0.0.0.0/0.  So, the question is: how does one call an ALB from within an ECS instance (User - ALB - Instances - ALB - Instances)?

Comment: It probably depends on your networking configuration. I think setting the SG to allow traffic from all destinations is not enough, but I would definitely check the routing tables.